# Ember.js server side form validation display

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I have a form in Ember JS and I want to:

**1. Display the errors for the fields right next to each field in error ;**

**2. Display any general errors at the top of the form ;**

**3. Have these errors persist while the user correct the form.**

Edit: [JSBin here](http://jsbin.com/motuvaye/2/edit)

I have the following template for the form:

```
{{#if isSaving}}
  <p>Saving Record</p>
{{/if}}
{{#if isError}}
  <p>There was an error saving the record</p>
  Base errors( {{errors.base}} )
{{/if}}
<form {{action 'create' this on='submit'}}>
  <p>Title: {{input type="text" value=title}}</p>
  <p>Title Errors(  {{errors.title}}  )</p>
  <p>Body: {{textarea value=body}}</p>
  <button>Create</button>
</form>
```

Right now my server is returning the following

```
{"errors":{"body":["can't be blank"],"title":["should begin with a capital letter"],"base":["General error message here"]}}
```

`errors.title` above is returning an object.  How can I get the message out of it.

When the user starts typing, the object message is wiped out.

The `isError` never seems to fire.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

errors is an array, and the proper way to iterate over them is the following:

```
{{#each errors.fieldname}}
  {{this.message}}
{{/each}}
```

Answer (score 0):

First: Your `errors.title` is (like all the other properties of your server response) an `Array` so you'd get the title with `errors.title[0]`. As you cannot reference it like this from `Handlebars` directly you'd either have to provide it from the controller or pass your server response to a custom helper.

Second: It's hard (or better to say impossible) to tell why `isError` is never triggered/set without code...

Comment: I've added a JSBin where I've tried to replicate the error as best I can.  I would greatly appreciate if you would take a look.  Thanks for your answer here!

Comment: You are correct.  I'm going to post the working syntax in another answer.